# iOS Phonegap Bug: Overscroll issue when switching inputs in form

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

When switching between text fields in my iOS Phonegap 2.9 app, the top of the screen stretches down leaving a large white blank area. And when you leave the text field it usually leaves the white space making the app look deformed.

Not sure whats causing this. I even have DisallowOverscroll set to "true" and KeyboardShrinksView set to "false".

**Video:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFfduT-u9dw

**Screenshots:** [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfKhW.png) and [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjXgX.png)

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework such as iscroll?  if so, i've iscroll done what you've shown which can be fix by calling iscroll reset.

Comment: Nope, I am using native scrolling and plain ol' css/js.